# Define variable in "IF" does not work in PHP

Tags: php, operator-precedence

```
...
elseif ($notes = json_decode($op->notes) && isset($notes->newSet)){
           // $notes = json_decode($op->notes);
            $set = \App\Set::find($notes->newSet);
            $setTitle = $set->title;
        }
...
```

The above `elseif` statement generates an error `Trying to get property of non-object` regarding the line `$set = \App\Set::find($notes->newSet)`

Passing through this `elseif` block should mean that `$notes` is assigned in `elseif` and the value of `$notes->newSet` is found.

I don't know why the above snippet does not works! It only works if I uncomment `// $notes = json_decode($op->notes);`

The PHP version is 7.0.18

Comment: Hint: operator precedence.

Comment: @zerkms: Had me thinking for a while,but yes.

Comment: @zerkms This means the two conditions are evaluated as `true`. So how `$notes->newSet` is set?!

Comment: @SaidbakR please read the answer. Your expression is evaluated as `$notes = ( json_decode($op->notes) && isset($notes->newSet) )`. There are no 2 conditions, but just one assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @zerkms, because of operator precedence, the part of the expression following

```
$notes =
```

is evaluated first, and in the success case,

```
json_decode($op->notes) && isset($notes->newSet)
```

evaluates to `true`, resulting in `$notes` being assigned `true`, rather than the `json_decode()`d data you want.

To fix this issue, wrap the assignment in parenthesis, and it will be evaluated first, and, as pointed out by @jh1711, make sure to verify that the decoded data is actually an object ( an instance of `stdClass`), rather than an array:

```
} elseif (($notes = json_decode($op->notes)) instanceof \stdClass && isset($notes->newSet)) {
    $set = \App\Set::find($notes->newSet);
    $setTitle = $set->title;
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Referenced @zerkms comment, do you really want me to repeat that?

Comment: no, I want you to either explain what's going on and why your answer would actually work, or don't bother at all. Although this is perfectly correct, he could easily find this answer by googling for "operator precedence". SO is not about flashing answers at will, it's about helping people to understand what's going so they'll learn and progress. Not for the one who asked this question, but for everyone ever coming back to this question in the future. Simply flashing out some code doesn't help for that goal, most of the times.

Comment: @giorgio Do you like this more?

Comment: yes, a lot more! :) I would only add that what you call `the right side of the expression` is whatever comes after `=` (this expression has actually three parts).

Comment: I thought about this a little more. $notes should only be assigned true, iff it was an object - containing the newSet property - before entering the else if clause. This probably happened in some code not in the question. If anybody wants to play around with a reduced case: https://3v4l.org/OhWcp

Comment: As you regarded `json_decode()` is evaluated to true and it does not return the json data. so how the next portion of `if` i.e `isset($nones->newSet)` which is should evaluate `false` and the block should not be evaluated. However, the block is evaluated!?! @localheinz

Comment: Adjusted the condition to verify the decoded data is actually an object, as suggested by @jh1711!

Comment: There are three possibilities what `json_decode($json)` could return: a) `false` on failure, b) an array, c) an object, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. See how they evaluate when casted to `bool`: https://3v4l.org/TP6ds.

Comment: @localheinz: I tried to make a slightly different point. `isset($notes->newSet))` is false after the evaluation of the elseif line, and you explained why. But `isset($notes->newSet))` must have been true during the evaluation. I only wanted to add that `isset($notes->newSet))` was true before we even got to code in the question.